# Set background-color of first word in textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an text box input in my HTML. I know how to set the background color of the whole thing with CSS (`background-color`) but is it possible to only set the background-color of the first word? I want it so that if someone types in, for example, "hello there", the background color of the word 'hello' will turn orange, but if they type in "how are you", the word 'how' will turn blue.

I have gotten it to style the whole textbox in [this JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/thatoddmailbox/ea7qbdLx/9/) with jQuery and CSS, but is it possible to make it only set the background color of the first word?

Comment: but only blue and orange right?

Comment: @MohitBhasi Yes. I use the CSS classes to change the background. I want the first word to be blue or orange and the rest to be white.

Comment: so only two cases when user inputs hello and how?

Comment: Not sure this is possible. You could however emulate the effect with a few css hacks.

Comment: @MohitBhasi Yes, only two cases.

Comment: @user2074704 Do you have any idea of which to use? I thought about using `:before` but that would go before even the first word.

Comment: There is an example it may help you http://jsfiddle.net/9AXvN/

Comment: There are the `::first-letter` and `::first-line` pseudo-elements, but not the `::first-word` one. Maybe a future spec will introduce it.

Comment: @AlimonKarim That might work except it uses HTML for styling (inserts a `span` element) and I don't think you can use HTML in textboxes.

Comment: I got really close , but not there yet . Hope this helps :http://jsfiddle.net/ea7qbdLx/1/

Comment: @MohitBhasi Thanks for helping. I am sorry if it is confusing, but I want to set the background color, not the text color.

Comment: I am sorry but it seems like JSFiddle has deleted my original code or I did not save it properly. I have updated the question with a fixed JSFiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick solution (not perfect) writen in few minutes, but maybe it help You to create better solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/ea7qbdLx/8/

HTML:

```
<div class="magic-input-container">
    <div class="form-control first-word"></div>
    <input type="text" id="textbox" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here..."/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('keydown keyup change', '.magic-input-container input', function (){

    if(($(this).val().length) && ($(this).val().split(' ').length)){

        $(this).closest('.magic-input-container').find('.first-word').html($(this).val().split(' ')[0]).show();
    }
    else{

        $(this).closest('.magic-input-container').find('.first-word').hide();
    }    
});


$(document).on('click', '.magic-input-container .first-word', function (){

    $(this).closest('.magic-input-container').find('input').focus();
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 10px;
}

.magic-input-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.magic-input-container .first-word {
    background: red;
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 6px 12px;
    padding: 0px 1px;
    border: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0px;
    display: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This works well, and the highlight stays in place when the text scrolls! I have marked yours as the accepted answer.

Comment: No problem. Tell me if You have any questions.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is no formatting style for such a textbox, textarea. But you can fake it. I have two idea:

1. Set background color of text input to transparent, then you create an colored background using span, div etc. Set position or margin so that text box is over the background.
2. Write or using an formated text editor that render text using html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').keyup(function(){
        var str= $(this).val();
        var idx = str.indexOf(' ') != -1?str.indexOf(' '):str.length;
        $('span').text(str.substr(0, idx));
        $(this).css('margin-left',-$('span').width()-6);
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="background-color:green; color:transparent">hello</span>
<input value="hello there" style="margin-left:-36px; background: transparent"/>
```

Comment: The second option seems to be overkill, as I just need to set this one color and don't need every other rich text editing feature. The first option looks good but I am not sure how to calculate the width of the 'hello' or 'how' text.

Comment: You can just put the word there

Comment: Who -1 without explain?

Comment: This looks like a good option but unfortunately the green highlight stays when you type past the screen and the textbox scrolls left. (for example, if you type 'hello there how are you') Is it possible to see how far the text is scrolled in JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find a way to calculate that. You can try extend textbox size and or limit the length that user can type

Comment: That's OK. Thank you for your help! I have marked your answer as the accepted answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

This is my version with minimal jQuery :)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <span id="bg"></span>
    <input id="inp" type="text" name="txt" size="60" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.container span {
    background: green;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.4
}
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var bgElem = $("#bg");
var inpElem = $("#inp");
bgElem.height(inpElem.outerHeight());

inpElem.on("keyup", function() {

    var val = $.trim( $(this).val() );
    var fword = val.split(" ")[0];
    var width = $("<span/>", { text: fword, css: { display: 'none' }}).appendTo("body").width() - 4;
    bgElem.width(width);
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gxsmkp1/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, your answer has the same problem that Trinh Hoang Nhu's answer does - if you type too much text, the textbox scrolls right but the highlight.