# Highlight first word in input using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, highlight

**Hello!**

I'm trying to make a terminal like interface, similar to PowerShell or Command Prompt.
I want to highlight the command name that the user inputs.
What I want in to look like:
[image: An image displaying in more context what I am trying to explain.]

Is there a possible way to do this with Javascript, CSS and HTML?
I am able to highlight the first word but it looks like this:
[image: An image showing what is happening in my website.]

I took some code from another post and here is what it looks like for me:
The post: [Set background-color of first word in textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797170/set-background-color-of-first-word-in-textbox)

```js
//=== MAIN ===\\
$(document).on(
  "keydown keyup change",
  ".terminal-input-area #terminal-input",
  function () {
    if ($(this).val().length && $(this).val().split(" ").length) {
      $(this)
        .closest(".terminal-input-area")
        .find(".first-word")
        .html($(this).val().split(" ")[0])
        .show();
    } else {
      $(this).closest(".terminal-input-area").find(".first-word").hide();
    }
  }
);

$(document).on("click", ".terminal-input-area .first-word", function () {
  $(this).closest(".terminal-input-area").find("#terminal-input").focus();
});
```

```css
/* ===== FONTS ==== */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code Retina";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-Retina.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code Light";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-Light.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code Medium";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-Medium.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code Semi-Bold";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-SemiBold.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code Bold";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-Bold.ttf");
}


/* ===== VARIABLES ==== */
:root {
    --background: #171717;
    --text: #aaa;
}


/* ===== STYLES ==== */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.terminal-container {
    background: var(--background);
    cursor: text;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.terminal-content {
    color: var(--text);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: "Fira Code";
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.terminal-input-area {
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.terminal-prompt {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#terminal-input {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: var(--text);
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.first-word {
    color: #F0BF81;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>coolterminalthing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="terminal-container" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="terminal-content">
            <div class="terminal-input-area">
                <span class="terminal-prompt">></span>
                <div class="form-control first-word"></div>
                <input name="input" id="terminal-input" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" defer></script>
    <script src="js/prompt.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you!

```js
//=== MAIN ===\\
$("#terminal-input").keyup(
  function () {
     const [first,...second] = $(this).val().split(" ");
      const f = `${first.length?first+" ":""}`
      $(this)
        .closest(".terminal-input-area")
        .find("#first")
        .html(f);
      $(this)
        .closest(".terminal-input-area")
        .find("#second")
        .html(`${second?second.join(" "):''}`);
    
  }
);

$(document).on("click", ".terminal-input-area .first-word", function () {
  $(this).closest(".terminal-input-area").find("#terminal-input").focus();
});
```

```css
/* ===== FONTS ==== */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code Retina";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-Retina.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code Light";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-Light.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code Medium";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-Medium.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code Semi-Bold";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-SemiBold.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fira Code Bold";
    src: url("fonts/FiraCode-Bold.ttf");
}


/* ===== VARIABLES ==== */
:root {
    --background: #171717;
    --text: #aaa;
}


/* ===== STYLES ==== */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.terminal-container {
    background: var(--background);
    cursor: text;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.terminal-content {
    color: var(--text);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: "Fira Code";
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.terminal-input-area {
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.terminal-prompt {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#terminal-input {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 37px;
    color: transparent;
    caret-color: white;
}

#first {
    color: #F0BF81;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>coolterminalthing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="terminal-container" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="terminal-content">
            <div class="terminal-input-area">
                <span class="terminal-prompt">></span>
                 <span id ="first"></span>
                 <p id="second"></p>
                <input name="input" id="terminal-input" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" defer></script>
    <script src="js/prompt.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Life saver! Thanks so much! I'll mark your answer as the correct one.